# zipkin 2.6 with rabbitmq collector

Tags: rabbitmq, zipkin

I am trying to run zipkin with rabbitmq collector enabled, like this:

```
$ RABBIT_ADDRESSES=tracing:5672 java -jar zipkin.jar
```

I can resolve tracing to an IP address and port 5672 is open. A queue called zipkin has been created in RabbitMQ.

Here is the exception thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMq' defined in class path resource [zipkin/autoconfigure/collector/rabbitmq/ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [zipkin.collector.rabbitmq.RabbitMQCollector]: Factory method 'rabbitMq' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at zipkin.server.ZipkinServer.main(ZipkinServer.java:26) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [zipkin.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [zipkin.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [zipkin.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [zipkin.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [zipkin.collector.rabbitmq.RabbitMQCollector]: Factory method 'rabbitMq' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.setUri(ConnectionFactory.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at zipkin.autoconfigure.collector.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorProperties.toBuilder(ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorProperties.java:132) ~[zipkin-autoconfigure-collector-rabbitmq-2.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at zipkin.autoconfigure.collector.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorAutoConfiguration.rabbitMq(ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorAutoConfiguration.java:43) ~[zipkin-autoconfigure-collector-rabbitmq-2.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at zipkin.autoconfigure.collector.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a3fd8a5.CGLIB$rabbitMq$0(<generated>) ~[zipkin-autoconfigure-collector-rabbitmq-2.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at zipkin.autoconfigure.collector.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a3fd8a5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9abe260.invoke(<generated>) ~[zipkin-autoconfigure-collector-rabbitmq-2.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at zipkin.autoconfigure.collector.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a3fd8a5.rabbitMq(<generated>) ~[zipkin-autoconfigure-collector-rabbitmq-2.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried it with an older version, 2.4.0, and there it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I think. I changed it to this:

RABBIT_URI=amqp://user:password@tracing:5672